# Is it possible to take sample_weight in account with MLPclassifier

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, weights

I am building 4 different models on the same dataset (classification tree (CT), random forest (RF), logistic regression (LR) and neural network (NN)).

Here is my dataset structure:

- Rows correspond to each day
- Dependant variable tells if that day had an avalanche (event) or not (non-event)
- Dependant variables was originally continuous (1, 2, 3, 4, etc. events par day), but I
  transformed it to binary (non-event = 0 and event = 1).

Event though the dependant variable is now binary, it is still important to give more weight to days with several events than days with only one event.

Sample_weight can be used directly in the fit(X, y[, sample_weight]) command for CT (DecisionTreeClassifier), RF (RandomForestClassifier) and LR (LogisticRegression), but it isn’t working the same way for NN (MLPclassifier). I am thus wondering if there is any other way to consider the sample_weight for the MLPclassifier model (NN)?

Comment: Why transform the dependent variable to binary?

Comment: @Dave Because my goal is only to predict if it will be an event or a non-event day. I don't want to predict the number of event per day. But the number of event is still important for the training because the model needs to allow more weight to days with more events.

Comment: That does not make sense to me. What happens when you go to predict new data and don’t know how many events were in the day?

Comment: @Dave That's the thing. I don't want to predict how many events per day. I just want to predict if it is an event or a non-event day.

Comment: But what you propose seems to use the number of events in the day to predict if there were any events in the day. You don’t need machine learning to do that, just an if-else statement.

Comment: What I propose is to train the model on 70% of the entire dataset in order to build a model able to predict if days in the future will be event or non-event (dependant variable) based on multiple (100+) independant meteorological variables (e.g precipitation, temperature, wind...). Once the model is built, I will test its performance on the 30% that it hasn't seen and compare it's predictions (event or non-event predicted) with what really happended (event or non-event in real world). I will thus have an idea of it's future performance on unseen data in the future. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

If Scikit-learn's API doesn't support the [sample weights](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/machine-learning-what-why-how-weighting.html) for this model, you can't use it there. In such a case, you would need to code it yourself, for example [Keras does support sample weights](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/). Implementing it yourself is rather straightforward, since weighted loss [means](https://medium.com/gumgum-tech/handling-class-imbalance-by-introducing-sample-weighting-in-the-loss-function-3bdebd8203b4) just that you calculate the overall loss as $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i \; loss_i$ with $w_i > 0$ so multiplying each sample by the weight $w_i$ behaves as if you observed it $w_i$ times more (or less) often in the dataset. Notice however that there are research results ([Byrd and Lipton, 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.03372)) showing deep learning models can learn to ignore the weights if trained long enough, so it can be a little bit more tricky fpr this class of algorithms.